# A Sci-fi story where the protagonist joins a band of space pirates by pretending to cut off his penis

Tags: story-identification

This story’s only enduring scene has a Lonestar-type sketchy Han Solo knockoff protagonist forced while infiltrating a group of space pirates to perform a gang initiation style act of hazing to show his allegiance.

For whatever reason escapes me now, he boasts that he’ll get rid of his… ahem, “pistol” — and not the one in his holster, but below his belt — and manages to successfully execute the charade by faking up a prosthetic and then whac— ummm, ahem, “cutting” it off.

I’m not sure if it was an anthology short story or part of single novel-length story. I’m pretty sure I read it maybe in early 1990s but I don’t recall if it was new. Humor was this level of Ice Pirates sophomoric locker-room type of humor.

Comment: Ice Pirates would have been my guess (I remember a scene involving castration of characters and some of the main characters faking it). But you already mentioned it, so I don't think it is.

Comment: Yeah. Certain it wasn’t novelization of Ice Pirates, if there even was one. The prosthetic was the ummmm… the frank, not the beans, and just involved the hero.

Comment: Is it true that the Pirates died out because they never had kids?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit of a long shot, but this might be from the second book in the Eagleheart series by C.T. Westcott, *[Broadsides and Brass](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5252322-broadsides-and-brass)*

It was a 3-book series published around the right time, the character is about right and the scene you describe is pretty much word-for-word what happens in the book. The humour sounds about right too!

The main deviation is that the series is set on Earth in a semi-post-apocalyptic near-ish future.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that is it.  I thought it was space not post-apocalyptic earth but that cover is familiar. Thank you. You would not believe my Internet search history looking for this thing, lol.